# Switching constant places in Fitch proof

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I'm trying to establish a Fitch proof regarding this
[question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaE1K.png) but I keep getting stuck.

$$\forall x \forall y \; Rxy  \quad\vdash_F\quad \forall y \forall x \; Ryx$$

To be honest I have no idea how to get from the premise to the conclusion. I can't figure out to switch the constants' places. Do I have to show that $x=y$?

Comment: *Remember:* When using $\forall$-introduction, the bound variable need not be the arbitrary variable .

Comment: Please edit your question to show your work and how you're getting stuck. As a hint, look at the universal elimination and introduction rules again - when can you use them?

Comment: You've trapped by the intentionally written *appearance* of the problem to let you think you need to show x=y or some symmetry of the relations R. But recall x,y are both bound variables here and thus can be renamed arbitrarily so long as they can still be identified. With this understanding you'll be more clear how to name things during a formal proof using ∀ elim/intro rules...

Comment: They are not "constant" but *argument places*.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $~$ You can show that $~~\forall x~Px \vdash_{\small F} \forall y~Py~~$ by:

$\def\fitch#1#2{~~~~\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}\fitch{~~1.~\forall x~Px}{\fitch{~~2.~\boxed a}{~~3.~Pa\quad\forall E~1}\\~~4.~\forall y~Py\quad\forall I~2{-}3}$

So do something similar...